# Wordpress check if current taxonomy has child

Tags: php, functions

I have a problem with displaying taxonomy on the site taxonomy.php
I have such a structure:

- Level 1

  - sub-level 1

    - sub-sub-level 1
    - sub-sub-level 2
  - sub-level 2

    - sub-sub-level 1
    - sub-sub-level 2

I do not know how to display custom taxonomy in some way. I would also like to click on sub-level 1 to display sub-level 1 and sub-sub-level 2, and if no child is found, the posts from this clicked taxonomy showed up. Please help me

Comment: Where do you want to display the result of the click ? on the same page with AJAX ?

Answer (score 1):

There is solved:

```
$taxonomy_name = 'listing_category';
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

$termchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy_name, array( 'parent' => $term_id, 'hide_empty' => false ) );

echo '<ul>';
   foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
       echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $child->name . '</a></li>';
   }
echo '</ul>';
```